# How is Gnote different from Tomboy?

Tags: tomboy, gnote

From what I have seen, they look absolutely similar and their functionality are pretty much the same.

See the attached image:

[image]

Comment: gnote is a port of tomboy..so it is not meant to be different than tomboy. Its just that it lacks some feature that tomboy has and is mono free.

Comment: Gnote doesn't have a notification-area icon, which could significantly affect UX: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452120/system-tray-icons-for-gnote-and-mail-notification

Comment: [Tomboy](https://github.com/tomboy-notes/tomboy) is no longer actively developed since 2017, and is no longer included in the Ubuntu repositories. The authors now work on [tomboy-ng](https://github.com/tomboy-notes/tomboy-ng) (which stands for Tomboy Next Generation). It's available in the Ubuntu repositories, install it by running: `sudo apt install tomboy-ng`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Gnote](http://live.gnome.org/Gnote) is a port of Tomboy to C++.

**Pros:** Faster, smaller memory footprint.
**Cons:** (Still) No synchronization support (e.g. Ubuntu one), which is a dealbreaker for most people.

You can [read about the author's motives here](http://www.figuiere.net/hub/blog/?2009/07/27/680-why-i-did-write-gnote).

> It is the same note taking application, including most of the add-ins
>   (more are to come). Synchronization support is being worked on.

[Tomboy is not going to be installed by default](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/banshee-tomboy-and-mono-dropped-from-ubuntu-12-04-cd/) in Ubuntu 12.04 - I suppose Gnote may take its place some day.

Comment: yes indeed this is the correct answer