# Looking for a notes management software

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a simple note management software ,  support searching article by title , any recommendations ?

Best not KDE's.

Comment: First of all, have you used either Tomboy or Gnote?  Seems like it would fit the description, but since one or the other comes with the systems, one might think you've tried it already (gnote is a rewrite of Tomboy, using a different library/language).

Comment: @MartyFried, probably it is created for an answer no matter OP edited it. Just read your profile, I did 6502 assembly at 1978, all the best to you, healthy and happy everyday and the next days :)

Comment: the OP better afore mention he has Wine running his Microsft Windows Notepad to him is Great and no problem at all.

Comment: @Rony: 1978! I was just starting to learn about microprocessors and digital electronics.  It was a few years later that I built my Z80 system and started really learning.  Haven't stopped learning yet!

Comment: @warlock:  I just double-checked a clean install of 12.04, and I see that neither Tomboy nor gnote are installed by default any longer.  Tomboy used to _always_ be installed with Gnome for every distro I've used, and I assumed one of them would still be available. I guess this is part of Ubuntu's new philosophy of giving choice to the users...  sorry, I couldn't resist that.

Comment: @MartyFried, IIRC Ubuntu 12.04 is Mono-free

Comment: @MartyFried, I bet you owned Radio Shack TRS-80 at that time? I am still learning hard but narrowing down much for time is mean-er and mean-er. So much to share and discuss and keep up right. :D

Comment: I played with one, but I had an S-100 homebuilt from Northstar Horizon reject parts (bare circuit boards, chassis parts).  I learned my first lesson - don't buy un-needed flexibility with computers; I had 10 extra slots I never used.

Comment: @MartyFried, my first take before Atari 6502 was ... zinclair, evermind, memory deserves good treasuring, do you mind share your site so I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Tomboy` [image], a very good notes management software

### Description:

> Tomboy is a free and open-source desktop notetaking application written for Unix-like (including Mac OS X and Linux) and Microsoft Windows operating systems, written in C# using Gtk#. Tomboy is part of the GNOME desktop environment, often for personal information management. Its interface is a notepad with a wiki-like linking system to connect notes together. Words in the note body that match extant note titles become hyperlinks automatically, making it simple to construct a personal wiki.

### Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

### Download

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [zim](http://www.zim-wiki.org/) for its [usage](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Usage.html) and [plugins support](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Plugins.html)

There is a [screencast](http://youtu.be/yBZpWgzO9Ps) uploaded on May 2009.

While Gnote is a port of Tomboy to C++
https://askubuntu.com/a/77046/62797

Comment: +1 for reminding me about zim; I had installed it, and liked it except that I have a lot of stuff in gnote, imported from Tomboy, and other stuff on Google Docs.  Can't seem to import either, except maybe cut and paste plain text.  Anyone know of a way to import anything else?  HTML would be nice, as most can export to HTML.

Comment: @MartyFried, tiddlywiki is truely great, but has to live with a single ever growing html file. It works with Firefox well.

Comment: Thanks; I tried that, too, but found it to be either too much or too little.  I even installed Wiki Media (used by Wikipedia) on my server, but that's overkill for my simple notes.  Tomboy/gnote are almost perfect, except that they are dead-ends because they can't be moved to something else (with the formatting), if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Tomboy is best..

With ability to sync with UBUNTU ONE,etc it would be my top prefrance.

Plus you can use the notes/memos/tasks feature from evolution.

Also,if you would like a Widget (like in windows 7) you can use SCREENLETS which is available in the software center.It has the ability to sync with tomboy.

Also NITRO is a good app.Though nitro is a task app basically,notes can be stored too.

If you need any help with the installations of any of it,just post a comment here.
Will be happy to help :)