# System tray icons for Gnote and Mail-Notification

Tags: unity, gnote, mail-notification

After upgrading my desktop from Precise to Trusty, some icon notifications are not shown anymore. Specifically they are the ones for **Gnote** and **Mail-Notification**.

How can I get them back?
I run Unity desktop environment.

Comment: have you installed libappindicator ?

Comment: libappindicator1 and libappindicator3-1 are installed. Shall I try to remove libappindicator1?

Comment: I dunno, sorry !

Comment: Removing libappindicator1 did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timekiller ppa should be ok in near future, it appears he forgot to patch the trusty build.

In the meantime try here, gnote should work to whatever extent it does.

https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/systray-white

Note it's a global re-enabling, just enable in app's settings if need be. Also there is a unity upgrade in trusty-proposed so at some point this build won't be an upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I was looking for something the other days and I found [**this**](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) among other stuff I was looking for. Hope it will work or at least will offer you an idea on how to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Ragnar. Unfortualntely, this did not work on my installation.